# R Download data from the internet in multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I want to load data for cryptocurrency-time-series-data from the "crypto"-package and split it in multiple dataframes. Here ist my code for 5 crypto-currencies:

```
Bitcoin <-crypto_history('bitcoin', start_date = '20181201', end_date = '20181231')
Ethereum <-crypto_history('ethereum', start_date = '20181201', end_date = '20181231')
XRP <-crypto_history('xrp', start_date = '20181201', end_date = '20181231')
EOS <-crypto_history('eos', start_date = '20181201', end_date = '20181231')
Theter <-crypto_history('tether', start_date = '20181201', end_date = '20181231')
```

This code works but for every dataframe of crypto-currency I have to assign a own code.
Is there a way to download all data in one function and put them in different dataframes (For example with a `map()` or `apply()`-function or a for-loop?
Because I want to to download 100 dataframes of crypto-currencies.

This code gives me the following output:

```
cryptos <- tribble(
  ~coin, ~start, ~stop,
  "bitcoin", "2018/01/01", "2018/01/02",
  "ethereum", "2018/01/01", "2018/01/02",
  "xrp", "2018/01/01", "2018/01/02"
)

cryptodat <- cryptos %>%
  mutate(history = pmap(list(coin, start, stop), ~crypto_history(..1, start_date = ..2, end_date =..3) ))

> cryptodat
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  coin     start      stop       history               
  <chr>    <chr>      <chr>      <list>                
1 bitcoin  2018/01/01 2018/01/02 <data.frame [30 x 13]>
2 ethereum 2018/01/01 2018/01/02 <data.frame [30 x 13]>
3 xrp      2018/01/01 2018/01/02 <data.frame [30 x 13]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to use the `crypto` package properly to give you a working example, but hopefully this will help you:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(purrr)

cryptos <- tribble(
  ~coin, ~start, ~stop,
  "bitcoin", "2018/01/01", "2018/12/01",
  "ethereum", "2018/01/01", "2018/12/01",
  "xrp", "2018/01/01", "2018/12/01"
)


cryptodat <- cryptos %>%
  mutate(history = pmap(list(coin, start, stop), ~data.frame(coin = ..1, date = seq.Date(from = as.Date(..2), to = as.Date(..3), by = 1))))
```

Using the `purrr` packages you get a nested dataframe.
Replace my part `~data.frame(coin = ..1, date = seq.Date(from = as.Date(..2), to = as.Date(..3), by = 1))` with the `crypto_history()` function.

Comment: Error: Can't convert a `data.frame` object to function

Comment: did you run this exact piece of code or replaced the function part `~data.frame()`?

Comment: Yes I replaced your part:     ~data.frame(coin = ..1, date = seq.Date(from = as.Date(..2), to = as.Date(..3), by = 1))  with the crypto_history() function

Comment: replace it with: `~crypto_history(..1, start_date = ..2, end_date =..3)` (you need the `~` for the correct evaluation. You might need to change the date format in the `tribble()` function.

Comment: The problem is that the dataframes are saved in the history-column. You can see it now in my question.

Comment: how can I split the history-column in different dataframe?

Comment: It is not a problem. You can use these data in numerous ways now. But you might want to learn a bit more about data wrangling in R using `tidyverse`.

Comment: how can I split the history-column in different dataframe?

My advice is to keep this data in a nested dataframe like this. Since working with 100+ separate dataframes at once is not efficient.